# Symplectic Chern class and and cohomology class of symplectic form

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $f: M \to N$ be a symplectomorphism and $\omega_N$ a symplectic form on $N$. I want to calculate the symplectic chern class $c_1(TM, f^* \omega_N)$.

Assume that I know a symplectic form $\omega_M$ on $M$ with $[\omega_M] = [f^*\omega_N]\in H^2(M;\mathbb R)$ and $c_1(TM, \omega_M)=0$.

Can I conclude that $c_1(TM, f^*\omega_N)=0$?

Edit: Actually, I know more than that $[\omega_M] = [f^* \omega_N]$. I know that $f$ is homotopic to a symplectomorphism $g$ with $g^* \omega_N = \omega_M.$

Edit2: $f$ is a covering map

Comment: I expect the answer to the question without the edit is NO. I am not so such about the situation with the edited conditions.  Since the homotopy is not through diffeomorphisms, the corresponding family of 2-forms are not all symplectic, i.e.. the most obvious method does not go through (But, note that the answer is YES if you assume the homotopy is in fact an isotopy, I can give the argument if you want). It might be quite difficult to cook up counterexamples. I will think more about this if I get time.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $M,N$? Are they closed? Do they have the same dimension? What else do you know on $f,g$ and the homotopy? For closed equidimensional manifolds,  the answer to your edited question is YES: $f$ is a covering map and has the unique homotopy lifting property; there's a diffeomorphism $H:M \to M$ such that $g = f \circ H$ thus $H$ intertwines the tame/compatible a.c.s. of $\omega_M = g^*\omega_N$ and $f^*\omega_N$. Otherwise the question is much more subtle and is reminiscent of work of McDuff, Ruan, McMullen-Taubes, Smith, etc. on nonequivalent symplectic forms.

Comment: @NickL: What is a homotopy through diffeomorphisms, and what is the difference between an isotopy and a homotopy? Maybe I could apply your approach

Comment: @JordanPayette: Actually, $f$ is a covering. What does it mean to inertwine almost cx structures?

Comment: Given a symplectic diffeomorphism $H : (M, \omega_M) \to (M, f^*\omega_N)$, each almost complex structure $J'$ tamed by/compatible with $\omega_M$ is of the form $J' = H^*J := H^{-1}\circ J \circ H$ with $J$ an almost complex structure tamed by/compatible with $f^*\omega_N$; $J'$ and $J$ are intertwined by $H$. Of course, $H^*(TM) = TM$. By naturality of the Chern class, $c_1(TM, \omega_M) = c_1(TM, J') = c_1(H^*(TM, J))= H^*c_1(TM,  J) = H^*c_1(TM, f^*\omega_N)$. Furthermore, since here $H$ is homotopic to $id_M$, it follows that $H^* = id$ on cohomology groups.

Comment: @JordanPayette Thank you. Do you know where I can read more about it?

Comment: What do you want to look for? Most of what I described is "elementary" algebraic topology, so there are plenty of resources on these subjects. Since you assume that $f$ and $g$ are covering maps, the pulled back symplectic forms are used merely in order to single out the (tamed/compatible) almost complex structures on $TM$; from that point forward, your question is no longer a symplectic geometric one.

Comment: @JordanPayette: I did not assume that $g$ is a covering map, only $f$.

Comment: Since you assume f is a covering map, M and N have the same dimension. Since you assume g pulls back $\omega_N$ to a symplectic form, $g$ is an immersion. Now I assume that $M$ and $N$ are closed, there is well-defined notion of degree for $f$ and $g$. Hence $g$ is a covering map too. Since you assume that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, $f$ and $g$ have the same degree. (Anyway, closedness of M and N is not necessary here, a slightly different argument works. But it would be good if you could clarify what are all your hypotheses, since, as I mentioned, it might affect the answer a great deal...)